# Use angularjs filter with parameters in the json

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I want to filter a list and get all the elements which have an argument equals to true. But my argument is a property and I don't know how to tell to angularjs to compute it.

```
{{ list | filter: {argument: true} }}
```

For instance if I have scope.argument = 'foo' my html should interpret it like this

```
{{ list | filter: {'test': true} }}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I create a filter in my controller

```
scope.isSelected = function(element) {
    return element[scope.argument] === true;
}
```

and then I use it in my html like this

```
{{ (list | filter: isSelected).length }}
```

I would prefer to do this directly in my html but I didn't find a way to do it.